# how to add Jquery variable inside wrapper

Tags: jquery

i am dynamically adding labels when i am clicking button.But i want it be displayed as label 1,label 2,label 3 etc.How to add jquery variable inside append.
This is my code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var max_fields = 10;
  var wrapper = $(".container1");
  var add_button = $(".add_form_field");

  var x = 1;
  $(add_button).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (x < max_fields) {
      x++;
      $(wrapper).append('<div><label><b>Assignment </b></label><a href="#" class="delete"> Delete </a></div>');
    } else {
      alert('You Reached the limits')
    }
  });

  $(wrapper).on("click", ".delete", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
    x--;
  })
});
```

```css
.container1 input[type=text] {
  padding: 5px 0px;
  margin: 5px 5px 5px 0px;
}

.add_form_field {
  background-color: #1c97f3;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid #186dad;
}

input {
  border: 1px solid #1c97f3;
  width: 260px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 14px;
}

.delete {
  background-color: #fd1200;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container1">
  <button class="add_form_field">Add Assignments &nbsp; <span style="font- 
     size:16px; font-weight:bold;">+ </span></button>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Here is my fiddle
i want like assignment 1,assignment 2 etc
http://jsfiddle.net/f5n2qhzv/243/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code for add and remove assignments.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var max_fields = 10;
  var wrapper = $(".container1");
  var add_button = $(".add_form_field");

  var x = 1;
  var counter = 1;
  $(add_button).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (x < max_fields) {
      x++;
      $(wrapper).append('<div><label><b>Assignment <span class="class_counter">'+counter+'</span></b></label><a href="#" class="delete"> Delete </a></div>');
      counter++;
    } else {
      alert('You Reached the limits')
    }
  });

  $(wrapper).on("click", ".delete", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
    //update current container's div counter
    $( " .container1 > div" ).each(function( index ) {
        $(this).find("label b span").text(index);
    });
    x--;
    counter--;
  })
});
```

```css
.container1 input[type=text] {
  padding: 5px 0px;
  margin: 5px 5px 5px 0px;
}

.add_form_field {
  background-color: #1c97f3;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid #186dad;
}

input {
  border: 1px solid #1c97f3;
  width: 260px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 14px;
}

.delete {
  background-color: #fd1200;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container1">
  <button class="add_form_field">Add Assignments &nbsp; <span style="font- 
     size:16px; font-weight:bold;">+ </span></button>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: When you delete assignements, you reorder, but when you add new assignements after the deletion, there is a gap in the numbering. Is that something known and wanted ?

Comment: @TakitIsy, please check now.

Comment: Yep, that seems more coherent !

Answer (score 0):

Below is your code with a new variable `i` that increments the name of the assignment.
I also modified the initial value of `x` to `0` so that the `max_fields` is actually `10`,
plus shorten the CSS by grouping identical styles of 2 classes.
(See my comments in the snippet)

In my opinion, the number of the assignment should be an unique identifier, and should not be changed even when other assignments are removed.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var max_fields = 10;
  var wrapper = $(".container1");
  var add_button = $(".add_form_field");

  var x = 0; // Modified so that the maximum is really 10
  var i = 0;
  $(add_button).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (x < max_fields) {
      i++;
      x++;
      $(wrapper).append('<div><label><b>Assignment ' + i + '</b></label><a href="#" class="delete"> Delete </a></div>');
    } else {
      alert('You reached the limit (' + max_fields + ').'); // Here I added max_fields in the message
    }
  });

  $(wrapper).on("click", ".delete", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
    x--;
  })
});
```

```css
.container1 input[type=text] {
  padding: 5px 0px;
  margin: 5px 5px 5px 0px;
}

/* Added this part which regroup the styles used in both classes */
.add_form_field, .delete {
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.add_form_field {
  background-color: #1c97f3;
  /*border: none; <-- This is not used, you modify it right below */
  padding: 8px 32px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 1px solid #186dad;
}

.delete {
  background-color: #fd1200;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  font-size: 14px;
  border: none;
}

input {
  border: 1px solid #1c97f3;
  width: 260px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 14px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container1">
  <button class="add_form_field">Add Assignments &nbsp; <span style="font- 
     size:16px; font-weight:bold;">+ </span></button>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: you just did for Add what about Remove part?

Comment: @Riddhi , What do you want to do on remove ? For me, the number is an identifier of the assignment, and should not be changed even on remove.

Comment: yes you are right I appreciate your answer but he didn't specify what actually `@Abdul Ashif` wants and I just thought if it is not an ID for an Assignment and it is just normal counter for it then we have to update the number of LABEL.